Lower bound for the product formula complexity in terms of spectral norm
The $\tilde{\alpha} t^{1+1/p} \epsilon^{-1/p}$ bound on gate complexity for simulating time evolution with product formulas is very problem-specific and requires computing nested commutators.
On general grounds, can we say that in terms of the spectral norm $||H||$, the gate complexity cannot scale better than $(||H||t)^{1+1/p}\epsilon^{-1/p}$? The logic is as follows: rescaling the Hamiltonian by an overall prefactor is equivalent to rescaling the evolution time, $e^{-iHt}=e^{-i(H/\alpha)(\alpha t)}$, therefore, a better scaling with Hamiltonian spectral norm would imply that a better scaling with time is achievable.

Check out this paper on lower bounds for lattice Hamiltonians.  There, the bound is $\Omega(nt)$ with $n$ the qubit number. Typically you fix the norm of the individual terms in the Hamiltonian as $O(1)$ and then you only need to specify scaling in time and system size.

My question is specifically about simulation with product formulas, while the the paper you cited assumes near-optimal simulation of local blocks. BTW, notice that for Qubitization and for the algorithm you mention the gate complexity is precisely a function of $(||H||t)$, in accord with logic I described — and this is a tight bound. Now, while this is not the case for the upper bound of product formula complexity that people often cite, my question is on whether it is the case for the lower bound.

I was referring to Theorem 2, which gives you a lower bound of $\Omega(nt)$ for any quantum simulation (of 1D Hamiltonians).

I see, yes, this kinda matches the no fast forwarding intuition.
